# How to set values to the elements of DArray?

Tags: julia

I'm exploring the parallel computing of Julia and tried this:

```
a=dzeros(5);a[1]=5
```

but just got this error:

> ```
> setindex! not defined for DArray{{Float64, 1, Array{Float64, 1}}
> ```

Well, I thought the manual said `setindex!` is fully implemented by `DArray`. What have I missed?

I was using v0.2.1 for Windows 32-bit.

Comment: what does methods(setindex!) say? Is DArray listed anywhere in it's list?

Comment: @JeremyWall I see several `DArray`s in the list, but not sure if they are methods supporting what I want to do. (I'm still not so familiar with the syntax of Julia.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just an explorer too, but after reading [Julia's Distributed Arrays Docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.2/manual/parallel-computing/#distributed-arrays), I tried this which seemed to work.

```
$ ./julia 
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" to list help topics
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.0-prerelease+2703 (2014-04-22 18:57 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit 942ae42* (0 days old master)
|__/                   |  i686-redhat-linux

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.0-prerelease+2703
Commit 942ae42* (2014-04-22 18:57 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (i686-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2250  @ 1.73GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 32
  BLAS: libopenblas (DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm

julia> a=dzeros(5)
5-element DArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1}}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> localpart(a)[1]=5
5

julia> a
5-element DArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1}}:
 5.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia>
```

It seems that distributed arrays aren't "local" until you make them "local".

Comment: N.B.:  The 'localpart' of a DArray needs to be assigned on the 'proc/worker' where it exists.